# Table not showing up at all in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

i have recently been learning C# and ASP.Net core and i am currently trying to set up SQL server with my project. However when i try to edit or view the table it just comes out as blank.

[image: Image of SQL Server Blank Table]

I have already set up the connection string in the appsettings.json file

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=dotnet-prac; Trusted_Connection=true; TrustServerCertificate=True;"
  },
```

Code below is the DataContext file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace dotnet_prac.Data
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Character> Characters => Set<Character>();
    }
}
```

This is the DB setup code that is in the Program.cs file

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Please Note, I am also using VS Code as my IDE

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Was expecting a table to show up so that way i can edit each value

Comment: Do you have Hardware Acceleration enabled in Tools > Options? If so, disable it and restart SSMS.

Comment: Hardware Acceleration has been disabled from the start and the table still does not show unfortunately :(

Comment: What do you mean by "view" the table? As in you do a `SELECT * FROM {Your Table}` and you get no rows in the result set?

Comment: What version of SSMS are you running? Try doing a repair re-install. Also check the Windows Event Logs for errors relating to SSMS.

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific, by "View" i mean the table not showing up at all visually as you can see in the image above the table should be on the right

Comment: I have tried to modify a property and i am getting this error:
This backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or tables. (MS Visual Database Tools)

Comment: The Object Explorer view on the left doesn't update dynamically as in it doesn't add items as they get created, nor remove them as they get dropped. Is it possible that the `Characters` table has been dropped from your database? What happens if you right-click on the `Tables` node and select `Refresh`?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys thanks for the replies, I have managed to fix the issue.

Turns out i had to download the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: it should be a comment to your question

Comment: as there's no code change to fix this. this shouldn't be added as anwser. Instead it should be a comment to the question. 

Even better if we can delete this question